# What is the best way to check if user is authenticated in a GWT application?

Tags: java, security, gwt

I have a GWT application designed with the pattern of a singleton class loading up different "Screens" which are basically various composite widgets representing the different pages of my application.

```
public enum ContentContainer {

    INSTANCE;

    public void setContent(Composite content) {
        RootPanel.get("content").clear();
        RootPanel.get("content").add(content);
    }
}
```

I am using Apache Shiro to perform the authentication.

What design patterns should I use to require that several of my "Screens" require the user to be authenticated? I am currently thinking of having a second method in the singleton, `setAuthenticatedContent()`, which will perform a check to see if the user has been logged in. However, this seems pretty inelegant to me as I have to ensure that every single link/button that enables me to enter a Screen requiring authentication goes through `setAuthenticatedContent()` instead of `setContent()`.

Is there a better method available to me which I have not thought of yet?

Comment: You mean, in server or client code?

Answer (score 0):

How about having a second singleton which stores whether the user is logged in or not? Then your `setContent` method can just reference this and render content depending.

Or possibly just declare a `static` variable inside your existing singleton that would store this information.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dependency Injection` (Gin) to inject a singleton object (i.e. `CurrentUser.class`) into all your components that need to access the information.
Your `CurrentUser.cass` contains information whether the user is logged-in and maybe the user roles (ADMIN, USER, etc).

In order to populate your `CurrentUser.class` you can either make a request to the backend (using `RPC`, `RequestFactory` or `RequestBuilder`) or what I would recommend use a [dynamic host page](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/dynamic_host_page.html) approach and let the backend render out the user information into your HTML host page.
In the `onModuleLoad` method you can use a `Dictonary` or `JSNI` to retrieve the information from the HTML host page.

**IMPORTANT**: This appraoch is only for displaying and hiding UI controls. When a user actually performs a UI action you **ALWAYS** have to check on the backend if the user has permission to perfom the action. 
A malicious user can modify your `CurrentUser.class` instance on the client.